# ERROR Exiting Kafka due to fatal exception (kafka.Kafka$) java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No MetadataVersion with metadata version 14

Tags: apache-kafka, kraft

I'm trying to start Kafka-KRaft server, and I'm getting this error:

```
~/kafka_2.13-3.5.0$ bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/kraft/server.properties
[2023-09-05 01:28:23,226] INFO Registered kafka:type=kafka.Log4jController MBean (kafka.utils.Log4jControllerRegistration$)
[2023-09-05 01:28:23,552] INFO Setting -D jdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation=true to disable client-initiated TLS renegotiation (org.apache.zookeeper.common.X509Util)
[2023-09-05 01:28:23,682] ERROR Exiting Kafka due to fatal exception (kafka.Kafka$)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No MetadataVersion with metadata version 14
    at org.apache.kafka.server.common.MetadataVersion.fromFeatureLevel(MetadataVersion.java:431)
    at org.apache.kafka.metadata.bootstrap.BootstrapMetadata.recordToMetadataVersion(BootstrapMetadata.java:70)
    at org.apache.kafka.metadata.bootstrap.BootstrapMetadata.fromRecords(BootstrapMetadata.java:54)
    at org.apache.kafka.metadata.bootstrap.BootstrapDirectory.readFromBinaryFile(BootstrapDirectory.java:106)
    at org.apache.kafka.metadata.bootstrap.BootstrapDirectory.read(BootstrapDirectory.java:78)
    at kafka.server.KafkaRaftServer$.initializeLogDirs(KafkaRaftServer.scala:168)
    at kafka.server.KafkaRaftServer.<init>(KafkaRaftServer.scala:57)
    at kafka.Kafka$.buildServer(Kafka.scala:83)
    at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:91)
    at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
```

I just followed the instruction cited here:
https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart

Any ideas how to solve this error? New at Kafka. I'm using Mac.

Comment: Do you get the same error with version 3.5.1?